# not allow to navigate if any changes on form using $dirty and $pristine

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to stop navigation on my application if any form made changes and try to navigate without saving changes.

i want to show a dialog to show whether to save navigate or discard or cancel navigation action.

i'm using angular [ui.routing](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');

    $stateProvider
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: '/application/private/views/dashboard.html'
        })
        .state('websites', {
            url: '/websites',
            templateUrl: '/application/private/views/websites.html'
        })
});
```

i was planning to have implementation something like using angularjs service singleton

```
app.service('dirtyCheckService', function ($rootScope, dialogService){


});
```

and on controller level i can write a submit click like this

```
app.controller('formSubmitCtrl', function ($scope, dirtyCheckService){
dirtyCheckService.checkForm($scope).then(function(){
   //allow navigation
   },function(){
   //not allowed}
});
```

i'm not sure is there easy way exist already or not

thanks you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is: It is ok to move that kind of check into service/factory - for some further reuse. Also, here is some example at least to show how to - [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y7q7i4Qa8Ae7tdFi9fyw?p=preview)

A factory:

```
.factory('CheckStateChangeService', function($rootScope){

  var addCheck = function($scope){ 

    var removeListener = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart'
        , function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

          if($scope.form.$pristine)
          {
            return;
          }

          var shouldContinue = confirm("The form has changed" +
                 ", do you want to continue without saving");
          if(shouldContinue)
          {
            return;
          }
          event.preventDefault();
    }); 

    $scope.$on("$destroy", removeListener);
  };

  return { checkFormOnStateChange : addCheck };
})
```

And having a `view` like this:

```
<div>
    <form name="form">

      <dl>
        <dt>Name</dt>
        <dd><input type="text" ng-model="person.Name" />
        <dt>Age</dt>
        <dd><input type="number" ng-model="person.Age" />
      </dl>

    </form>
</div>
```

And the controller:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, CheckStateChangeService) {

  $scope.person = { Name: "name", Age: 18 };

  CheckStateChangeService.checkFormOnStateChange($scope);

})
```

There is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y7q7i4Qa8Ae7tdFi9fyw?p=preview)

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow. The `ui-router` is really awesome piece of code ;) Enjoy it ;)

Comment: yeah it's. for the dirty check i have found great alternative as well check this out [unSaveChanges](https://github.com/facultymatt/angular-unsavedChanges)

Comment: let say, one have direct download link, how it would behave I doubt it will still show warning message.

Answer (score 2):

You're right about a service being the way to do this, something like this should do:

```
$scope.$watch("myForm.$dirty",function(v){
     dirtyCheckService.setDirty(v);
},true)
```

Then maybe somewhere in your app, such as the run block:

```
app.run(function($rootScope,dirtyCheckService){
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, prev) {
       if(dirtyCheckService.isFormDirty()){
         event.preventDefault();
       }
    }
})
```

Of course the above will only work given that you set your form to pristine once the user saves their changes.

Comment: I'll second the '$locationChangeStart' event value I never saw a '$stateChangeStart' event fired and I don't think it's a valid angular event - at least, I don't see it in the angular source code anywhere.

Comment: @icfantv the $stateChangeStart event is a ui-router event: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events

Comment: Yea.  This was a year and a half ago.  I've learned much in 18 months.