# Handling page or tab change in angualajs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

How to detect unsaved page changes check while moving another page or tab in angularjs 1.5 application.
One of approach is using directives however how to pass related form named to the directive instead of using hard coded solution?

I tried using the service approach as mentioned below but my nested view controller is not able to access the form name. Iam getting $scope.myForm as undefined.

Comment: Check if this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777890/equivalence-of-window-onbeforeunload-in-angularjs-for-routes

Comment: Please be a lot more specific. Not clear at all what you are needing to do, how your tabs work or what `dirty page` even means. Should also include references to solutions you found and why they don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module below seem to work for me
https://github.com/facultymatt/angular-unsavedChanges

Answer (score 3):

You can handle page change with the event `$locationChangeStart` for ng-route or `$stateChangeStart` for ui-router (perform the logic you want inside):

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
    if ($scope.myForm.$invalid) {
       event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

To tab change etc, you can disable your tab with something like or watever approach you prefer

```
ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid"
```

**EDIT**

You may look at this post to use a service/factory approach :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25459689/5138917

Comment: Is it possible not to hard code the form name while using a service or directive?

Comment: Hi mate ! I dont know :/ ... But you may apply some personals naming conventions in your app to deal with that :)